# does it make sense to use something like backbone for a single page application created using Raphael?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, raphael

For the past six months or so I've been teaching myself Javascript by building a single page application that uses Raphael to create all of the elements the user sees and interacts with ([see the landing page](http://www.projectvalis.com) for the project for a small-scale example of what the tool will do). As I've been learning more about the language I've been coming across a lot of talk about using something like Backbone to structure the code such that it will be easier to read and maintain. While I'm not in love with the idea of taking what I've written and shoehorning it into an MVP paradigm (which would also require me to learn the paradigm), I am in favor of writing quality code that won't cause me headaches later. However, in the course of doing some google research, I've discovered that backbone doesn't seem to play nicely with SVG elements. True, there are some workarounds posted, but it seems to me that if I have to implement a kludgey work-around in order to get everything to work, the value of implementing Backbone in this case is lost as my code is still wonky, albeit in a different way. (ego compels me to point out that as it stands, the code is reasonably un-spagettified)

Given that I'm relatively new to Javascript, and to serious web programming in general, I'm posting this question here in the hopes of soliciting advice from persons more learned than I in matters such as these. If you were in my position, would you implement Backbone (or some equivalent) or would you proceed without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you keep doing what you are doing. The website looks good and responsive. Do not change anything as long as you think the code is easily maintainable and readable. When you see heavy loading and spaghetti code, then you might consider about using some `JS` structure.

Comment: makes sense - and thanks for responding! there are a lot of other challenges I need to address at this point and I wasn't relishing the thought of adding refactoring the code to conform to a new paradigm to the list.